# Spring in action 5th edition - chapter 1, STS setting problems

Tags: java, spring

I was learn the MEAP book -- spring in action 5th, every one can download chapter 1 and its code with the below url, free of charge.
https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fifth-edition
but I encounter problems when I try use Spring Tool Suite based on Eclipse, I just follow the steps but it shows me two errors.
[click here to see error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iVdR.png)
, why is the location of the second one unknown? I have search the Internet about "the project can not be built until path errors are resolved", I have clicked the "project -> Build Automatically" and then click "project->clean", also I've check there are all valid jar files in libraries path, but none of the tips work for me. And when I try to run by the Boot Dashboard
[boot dashboard pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZT66.png), 
it shows me that Error: Could not find or load main class tacos.TacoCloudApplication. 
[load error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v6wV.png)
So could any one pleaseeee help me with it, I download java 8 on my mac and the path is 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk

error image for lombok:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOM9a.png)
BTW, I start another project from the spring website--the RESTful API, below is the url, and amazing! The code just works very well and I can run it, so it shouldn't be the problem of my jdk1.8, see pics:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0JAA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysiW1.png)
So it seems that it is caused by the code from the Spring in action 5th, which is not functional by itself?

---important update----
I just found that there is no class files inside the lombok jar folder under Maven dependencies, why did this happen and how to fix it?
[no .class files in lombok jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLvzt.png)

Comment: Your error image is not quite in full form. Mention that `lombok` error in full sentence.

Comment: I had update error message and try another project with existing code, and that one just works fine, it should be a problem due to the book's code

Answer (score -1):

Did you do maven update project? `Right click the project and choose Maven -> Update Project` to get all the required dependencies and then try build and run

Comment: Hi, thank U for reply. I have tried maven update project, but the problem still exists.